# Handled signal in Python causes FTP connection to interrupt

Tags: python, signals

This scripts checks an FTP and download files at scheduled intervals.

Sending to it the right signal (SIGUSR1) should make it close gracefully, waiting checkAll to complete, if running.

```
class ScheduledFtpCheck(FtpCheck, Scheduler):
    def __init__(self):
         ...
         self.aborted, self.checking = False, False

    def abort(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.aborted = True
        if not self.checking: self.quit()

    def checkAll(self):
        if not self.isAborted():
            self.checking = True
            self.checkAll()
            self.checking = False
            if self.aborted: self.quit()

    ...

def main():
    sch = ScheduledFtpCheck()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, sch.abort)
    sch.start()
```

the problem is I get a Interrupted system call that makes ftplib.FTP exit prematurely:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/my-applications/sensor/sensor/lib/importutils2.py", line 137, in connectAndCheckAll
    try: self.checkAll()
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ftplib.py", line 182, in getline
    line = self.file.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 406, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call
```

So my script handles signal correctly but scheduled check don't.

Why? How can I prevent it?

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the solution:

running ftp process in a separate thread isolated it from main process signals

```
threading.Thread(target=self.checkAll).start()
```